# Comparison between Android Life Cycle & iOS Life Cycle

Tags: android, ios

Both android callback methods & iOS life cycle stages have similarities and differences.
For example If application in background , Android has onStop() callback method and iOS has
background stage?

I need to know differences and similarities between following iOS life cycle stages and Android life cycle.

- Not Running
- Inactive
- Active
- Background
- Suspended

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**Not Running** — Either the application has not started yet or was running and has been terminated by the system.

**Inactive** — An application is running in the Foreground but is not receiving any events. This could happen in case a Call or Message is received. An application could also stay in this state while in transition to a different state. In this State, we can not interact with app’s UI.

**Active** — An application is running in the Foreground and receiving the events. This is the normal mode for the Foreground apps. The only way to go to or from the Active state is through the Inactive state. User normally interacts with UI, and can see the response/result for user actions.

**Background** — An application is running in the background and executing the code. Freshly launching apps directly enter into In-Active state and then to Active state. Apps that are suspended, will come back to this background state, and then transition to In-Active → Active states. In addition, an application being launched directly into the background enters this state instead of the inactive state.

**Suspended** — An application is in the background but is not executing the code. The system moves the application to this state automatically and does not notify. In case of low memory, the system may purge suspended application without notice to make free space for the foreground application. Usually after 5 secs spent in the background, apps will transition to Suspend state, but we can extend the time if app needs.

Source: [This website](https://hackernoon.com/application-life-cycle-in-ios-12b6ba6af78b)